# react-bootstrap Carosuel not displaying when looping

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am looping to a set of images and rendering `<Carousel.Item>`. However `<Carousel.Item>` it's showing displaying whenever I am using the loop. Whenever I do not have an image and I render image as without the loop that seems to be working as expected. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
        <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div className="carousel-wrapper">
                  <Carousel>
                    {step.screenshots.length ? (
                      <>
                        {step.screenshots.map((screenshot: string, index: number) => {
                          return (
                            <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                              <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={`/api/p/task/results/${screenshot}`}
                                alt="First slide"
                              />
                            </Carousel.Item>
                          )
                        })}
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <Carousel.Item>
                        <img
                          className="d-block w-100"
                          src={`/api/p/task/results/5eb13cdb6cc3804560b955cc/step2/screenshot0`}
                          alt="First slide"
                        />
                      </Carousel.Item>
                    )}
                  </Carousel>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
```

[image]

Any thoughts on why this now showing up the the carousel when I am looping? How can I display the image without needed it overwrite the css?

I tried to specify the active index and that did not work either.

Comment: came over from discord -- happy to chat there;
Why are you treating the length 1 scenario differently? Also FWIW -- you should change your alt text to `Slide ${index}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you simplify your code to the following and report back:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <div className="carousel-wrapper">
        <Carousel>
          {step.screenshots.map((screenshot: string, index: number) => {
            <Carousel.Item key={index}>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src={`/api/p/task/results/${screenshot}`}
                alt={"Slide ${index}"}
              />
            </Carousel.Item>
          })}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```